# get value of dynamic ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

I want to get ng-model's value in scope varialbe

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="wing in getNumber(app.wingnum) track by $index">
            <label for="InputMessage">Enter name of Wing </label>
                <div class="input-group"  >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name=""                               placeholder="Enter Name of wings" 
                    ng-model="control[$index]" 
                     ng-keyup="addNewWing()"required/>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's your `ngModel` - you should have access to it via `$scope.control[indexValue]`

Comment: but i can't access $ index at controller
 $scope.addNewWing = function(){
 console.log($scope.control[1]);
 }

Comment: Pass `$index` in as a variable to the `addNewWing` function

Comment: thanks  :)  and i want your reference for add dynamic textbox by ng-repeat and get value of all textbox and pus into array you have any referance link

Comment: Can You update exact code? I am getting some issue. @tymeJV and what inside app.wingnum ?